# Why is “très” used with “avoir” in certain expressions?

Tags: grammaire, adverbes, auxiliaires

In expressions like *J'ai faim,* why is it correct to augment it by saying “*J'ai très faim*” instead of “*J'ai beaucoup de faim*”?

I mean, if the French way of saying *I'm hungry* is “*I have hunger*”, shouldn't it be embellished as “*I have a lot of hunger*”, rather than “*I have very hunger*”? That's assuming we translate *très* as *very*, which may not be entirely accurate, but is what I've always been told.

Comment: Excellent question! I would answer you should use "Je suis affamé(e)", which means "I am starving". As it doesn't answer your question, I put that in a comment ;-).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Le TLF [nous dit](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tr%C3%A8s) que c'est une forme impropre, mais la cite en effet.

> E. − [Employé improprement dans une locution verbale formée d'un auxiliaire ou d'un verbe support (*avoir*, *être*, *faire*, *prendre*…) et d'un substantif abstrait désignant des « sensations ou des sentiments à l'état brut: *faim*, *soif*, *froid*, *chaud*, *sommeil*, *mal*, *peur*, *envie*, *plaisir*, *honte*, *hâte*… » (G. Moignet, *op. cit.*, p. 154); emploi critiqué] *Un jour, elle se retrouva dans son lit, bien faible, ayant très faim* (A. France, *Jocaste*, 1879, p. 74). *Il faut que nous fassions très attention, il faut que nous soyons très prudents* (Guitry, *Veilleur*, 1911, iii, p. 19).

Et elle est si courante (à l'oral notamment, mais même à l'écrit) qu'elle ne choquera personne, hormis peut-être dans les contextes les plus formels.

Comment: In short, it's actually an improper usage of _très_, but the usage is extremely common so that nobody will consider it incorrect. Funnily enough, the link doesn't say what the proper form would be. _J'ai beaucoup de faim_ is certainly incorrect, so you'd have to use _J'ai une grande faim_ or _J'ai grand-faim_ (for extra pedantic points)  Anyway, go eat something already.

Comment: @Joubarc: Bloody crutial detail, isn't it rather *grand'faim*?

Comment: I thought so too, but nope. The [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/grand) mentions explicitely _grand-faim_ and also says a few things about it in the ethymology section, including _"Ces loc. étaient écrites, à tort, avec une apostrophe comme s'il s'agissait d'une élision."_

Comment: And speaking of bloody details, it's _crucial_, not _crutial_ ;-) (and you may want to be careful with the usage of [bloody](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12268/why-is-bloody-considered-obscene-in-the-uk-but-not-in-the-us) too, by the way)

Comment: Bloody isn't really considered obscene. It's very mild. Usage tends to be even higher in Ireland (more Catholic) than the U.K. I think Stéphane's usage could be interpreted as wishing to emphasize the importance of the detail in an informal, perhaps jocular way.

Comment: American reporting in; for me "bloody" is only very slightly more vulgar than "really".

Comment: And now I just learned *I'm a little hungry* is translated by *J'ai un peu faim* -- yet *J'ai beaucoup de faim* is wrong! Sigh. The illogic of it all.

Answer (score 2):

For the “grammatical correctness” of the expression, the accepted answer is perfect. I could just add that, as a native educated speaker, I was really surprised recently to discover the expression to be incorrect.

If one slightly generalizes the question to “why do almost all native speakers feel this is correct ?”, I think the answer is in Rodney Ball’s excellent *Colloquial French Grammar: A Practical Guide*, section 3.1.3 (here “standard” is short for “standard French”, the rest is colloquial French.)

> (d) Two further points of usage involving adjectives (and adverbs) should
>   be noted. Firstly, the widespread familiar use of **très** with certain nouns.
>   Expressions like j'ai **très froid/très chaud** are standard: **froid** and **chaud** here
>   are direct objects of **avoir**, but they are adjectives even so, and can therefore
>   be modified by the adverb **très**. Understandably enough, this causes **très** to
>   be adjoined to nouns like **faim**, **soif** or **envie** in the parallel expressions j'ai
>   **très faim/très soif/très envie
>    (standard **j'ai grand' faim/grand' soif/grande envie**). A further development is the still more familiar expression **faire très attention** (standard **faire bien attention**). Such uses are much criticized by normative grammarians, who see it as a breach of grammatical protocol for an
>   adverb to modify a noun.

Answer (score 1):

***J'ai faim / j'ai très faim*** sounds a bit like ***I'm starved / I'm very starved*** (or ***I'm hungry / I'm very hungry***), where ***very*** as the same meaning as ***très***. Being hungry (or starved) is a *final state*, while ***I'm starving*** is the *beginning of the processus*: ***je commence à avoir faim*** (a close meaning of ***je suis en train d'avoir faim***, barely used).