# I don't understand what to do with ‘peur’

Tags: anglais, comparaison-de-langues

Why is it "j’ai peur" instead of "je suis peur"?

And also is it okay to say "avoir peur"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a difference between "J'ai faim" et "Je suis faim"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11847/is-there-a-difference-between-jai-faim-et-je-suis-faim)

Comment: Welcome to French Language Stack Exchange! Please consider searching your topic before posting a new question since so many of the basics have been covered to death. There are questions on this from a variety of perspectives: [avoir vs. etre](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11847), [agreement of the second item](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29906), [intensification with "très"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6208) (P.S. it's not clear that it's a noun), and a [list of similar expressions](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/9380).

Comment: There is nothing that different between French and English here: *I am afraid* can be literally translated by *je suis effrayé* while *j'ai peur* is closer to *I have fear*.

Comment: @jlliagre Although technically grammatically equivalent, I don't think that's a good route to go. In the first place, "I have fear, I have hunger, I have thirst" etc. are rarely if ever used in English compared to this being the normal way in French, which suggests that the translation isn't apt. In the second place, such a mapping function does *not* produce valid English for all inputs: **I have cold*, **I have hot*, **I have sleep* are not good.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Yes. My point was about the fact peur and afraid do not match, and for that reason, the verb used are different. J'ai is also close to I feel so with you examples, that might be I am/feel chill, I feel warmth, I feel tiredness. Of course, these aren't the usual idiomatic ways to say it but I guess you got the idea.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, ***avoir peur*** in French mean ***being afraid*** in English.

The definition of "afraid" is the following:

> feeling fear or anxiety; frightened.

So the most important is to understand this is a feeling, which mean we won't use *to be / être* to express it.

In French (in general cases) we use:

Verbe **être / to be**  when talking about a condition.

> Il est malade. *He is sick.*
>
> Ils sont fatigués. *They are tired.*

Verbe **avoir / to have**  when talking about a feeling.

> Ils ont faim. *They are hungry.*
>
> Elle a peur. *She is afraid.*

---

So in **conclusion** we use "j’ai peur" instead of "je suis peur" because "being afraid" in French is considered a feeling and not a condition.

Comment: No categories will be fully coherent when applied to the full list.

Comment: Yes I agree that what I wrote can be confusing for a for a French native speaker, but I just did my best to make it clear for him to understand using simple examples.

Comment: Right, and it may be helpful for the couple of examples given, but it quickly breaks down with further data. One simple reason is that there are alternative wordings for many of these. Is hunger a feeling or a state/condition? *J'ai faim* but *Je suis affamé* ; *J'ai soif* but *Je suis assoiffé* ; *J'ai peur* but *Je suis effrayé* ; *J'ai mal* but *Je suis malade* ; *J'ai sommeil* but *Je suis fatigué*. The reason is not rooted in semantics. You can cover a lot of ground with a few grammatical rules ("Use *être* if it looks like a past participle") but even that won't work for all cases.

Comment: Yep I completely agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to translate is "I am scared." or "I am afraid.". In French you do not use "to be", that is "être", instead it's always "avoir" ; therefore you say this;

> J'ai peur.

"Je suis peur." is always incorrect.

The difference is that in English you use an adjective (afraid, scared), which is  an estate, that of being overwhelmed with fear in this case, whereas in French you use the corresponding noun instead (la peur). Obviously, you can't say "Je suis la peur." or "Je suis peur.". So, what you say is something as "I have in me the feeling of fear.", somewhat shortened (I have fear.).